# how to create try catch in drupal 8

Tags: forms, debugging

I would like to create a custom message when user did unexpected error it should show this message
 `Invalid parameter please enter correct values` . It should not show this message.
  `The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.` 
I would like to create

```
 try {
    ...

    }  
    catch{
        Invalid parameter please enter correct values;
    }
```

please help with simple example

Comment: You need to subscribe to the 500 error response (Symfony lets you do this), and react there. There's no single point in code you could put a `try...catch` and make it intercept the error you mentioned. The duplicate has a code example

Comment: this work for me `try{.... }
       catch (\Exception $e) {
 drupal_set_message("Thers is an  Error Occured.Please Contact Administrator", 'error');
    return new RedirectResponse(URL::fromUserInput('/error')->toString());
}    `